# a element in nested divs, jquery events not working

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors, anchor

i want to use an event of an anchor element in some nested div's but something is not working in my code.

i tried hundreds of variations on that selector but it still does not work.

html code:

```
<div class="tabContents">
  <div class="thumbArea">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="foo" alt="baba"/>
  </a>
  </div>
  <div class="imageArea">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

  $(".tabContents a").hover(function() {
  alert("just work!");
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery `hover` takes two functions, an "over" and an "out".

```
$(".tabContents a").hover(function() {
     alert("mouse over!");
   }, function(){
      alert("mouse out!");
});
```

If you're just looking for mouseover, I would suggest:

```
$(".tabContents a").mouseover(function() {
    alert("just work!");
});
```

**Further Response:**

Try using jQuery's `live` event. This will ensure that the event listener will also be paying attention for any new elements added to the DOM (like the ones you're appending). However, live does not currently support `hover`. You can do a `mouseover` and a `mouseout` event though to achieve the same effect.

```
$('.tabContents a').live('mouseover', function(){
   alert('mouseover!');
});

$('.tabContents a').live('mouseout', function(){
   alert('mouseout!');
});
```

I think I saw that somebody wrote an extension for jQuery that allowed for the use of 'hover' with `live` in a response to a question here on SO, so it can be done, but alas, I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: `jQuery.fn.liveHover=function(over,out) { if (over) this.live('mouseover',over); if (out) this.live('mouseout',out); return this;};` might work :)

Comment: @gnarf: That wasn't the way I saw it done, but I guess that means I got stuck "in the box". Much appreciated for pulling me out. ;)

Comment: @munch: your solution is exactly what i was looking for. thank you.

@gnarf: will i use it as an event or what ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code -- copied character-for-character -- is working perfectly for me.  (NOTE:  Firefox on Windows.)

Try using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and see if it can help identify what's happening for you.